# Laravel Eloquent pass variable to with relationship function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using eloquent to make a query for a database entry and it's corresponding relationship. The problem is I need to pass the `$date` variable into the relationship `query` like shown below:

I can pass the `$date` variable to the first query because its not inside a with function. How can I achieve this with the second?

**Query**

```
    public static function find_task($type, $date) {
    if($type == 'student') {
        $mySid = Student::student_id();
        $allTasks = TaskAssignment::where('student_id', $mySid)
            ->with('task')
            ->where('dueDate', $date)
            ->orderBy('dueDate', 'asc')
            ->get();

    } elseif($type == 'teacher') {
        $myTid = Teacher::teacher_id();
        $allTasks = Tasks::where('teacher_id', $myTid)
            ->with(['assignment' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('dueDate', $date);
                $query->orderBy('dueDate', 'asc');

            }])->get();
    } else {
        return 'error this page does not exist';
    }

    return $allTasks;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `use` in the closure

```php
->with(['assignment' => function ($query) use ($date){
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
$user = User::with(array('relationShipMethod' => function($query) use ($request) {
     $query->wherePivot('column', $request->column); 
}))->first();
```

relationShipMethod = method with you relationship another table for example users has posts maybe relationShipMethod could be posts method