# Laravel Eloquent how pass variable to with relationship function nested

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I wish to pass a variable to nested relationship with eloquent.
I read this [Laravel Eloquent pass variable to with relationship function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411826/laravel-eloquent-pass-variable-to-with-relationship-function) but in that answer it does not look at a nested relationship.

I've this scenario:

```
Category::where("company", $company)->whereNull("parent_ecommerce_id")->with(['children']);
```

My model

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,'parent_ecommerce_id','category_ecommerce_id')->with("children");
}
```

I can modify my first call with this as suggest in link posted

```
Category::where("company", $company)->whereNull("parent_ecommerce_id")->with(['children' => function($query) use ($company) {
    $query->where("company", $company);
}]);
```

and it works in first call, but in nested callback, I haven't more the filter with "company". How can I filter the company in all nested relationship? I thinked passing variable to "children($var)", but I don't find solution to pass that in "with" statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, I believe it should be more like this.

If what you are trying to achieve is to fetch all Categories that with children, where the companies have been filtered.

```
Category::where("company", $company)->whereNull("parent_ecommerce_id")->whereHas('children', function($query) use ($company) {
    $query->where("company", $company);
}])->with(['children']);
```

Comment: No, children is not a "column" of DB. Children is a relationship in model "Category". So I can't insert "whereHas" on relation...

Answer (score -2):

I think this way is not right, if there is necessary of a second variable filter, we must use another way to get all category tree as is explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFxR6D2kH44

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).